# What "soup" (definition) means in "triangle soup" or "polygon soup"?

Tags: graphics, definition

I have no idea what "soup" *literally* means when it is used in "triangle soup" or "polygon soup" regarding to computer graphics. Is it related to the "soup", we eat with spoon?

(I'm not a native English speaker.)

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia to the rescue!

> A polygon soup is a group of unorganized triangles, with generally no
>   relationship whatsoever. Polygon soups are a geometry storage format
>   in a 3D modeling package, such as Maya, Houdini, or Blender. Polygon
>   soup can help save memory, load/write time, and disk space for large
>   polygon meshes compared to the equivalent polygon mesh.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_soup

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know what the definition of "soup" is in general.

Comment: Soup is 국. In a soup, the ingredients are mixed together and are unorganized. Think of 순두부찌개. The idea is that many things are put together in an unordered or unorganized way.

Comment: Thank you for really kind Korean definition and example. :) Now I can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

When the faces of a polygon mesh are given but the connectivity is unknown, we must deal with of a polygon soup.

Polygon soup does not have any connectivity (each point has as many occurences as the number of polygons it belongs to).